# Adding textbox to UserControl in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple web page which has a UserControl(.ascx). Here is my **UserControl source**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ucReportTextBox.ascx.cs"
Inherits="Intranet.UserControl.ucReport" %>
<table width="100%">
<tr>
      <td>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuery" runat="server" Width="250px" />
      </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And my **web page source**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage/DefaultMasterPage.Master"
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ComposeReport.aspx.cs" Inherits="Intranet.MasterPage.WebForm4" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControl/UcReportTextBox.ascx" TagName="UcReportTextBox" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="contentHead" runat="server"/>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="contentBody" runat="server">
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>
           <uc1:UcReportTextBox ID="ucReporttxt" runat="server" />
       </td>
   </tr>
//includes so many tags
</table>
</asp:Content>
```

In **code behind of my web page**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitComponent();
    }

    private void InitComponent()
    {
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load("ReportXML.xml");
        var parameterTypes = document.Descendants("Type");

        foreach (var parType in parameterTypes)
        {
            if (parType.Value == "string") //TODO Enumerate it !!
            {
                ucReporttxt.addTextBox();
            }
        }
    }
```

In **code behind of usercontrol**

```
public void addTextBox() 
    {
        TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
        txtBox.ID = "txtBox";
        txtBox.Width = 170;
        Page.Form.Controls.Add(txtBox);
    }
```

As you understand I'm newer to asp.net , in PageLoad I'm reading XMLfile to whether or not add textbox to page. The codes add textboxes correctly but the textboxes are added at the end of the page. I want to add textbox at the part of `ucReportText` not the end of the page how can fix it ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an asp panel to the user control and add the textbox to the panel controls and not the page controls.  Then just place the panel where ever you want the textboxes to appear.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage/DefaultMasterPage.Master"
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ComposeReport.aspx.cs" Inherits="Intranet.MasterPage.WebForm4" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControl/UcReportTextBox.ascx" TagName="UcReportTextBox" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="contentHead" runat="server"/>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="contentBody" runat="server">
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>
           <uc1:UcReportTextBox ID="ucReporttxt" runat="server" />
           <asp:panel runat="server" id="pnlContainer"></asp:panel>
       </td>
   </tr>
//includes so many tags
</table>
</asp:Content>



public void addTextBox() 
    {
        TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
        txtBox.ID = "txtBox";
        txtBox.Width = 170;
        pnlContainer.Controls.Add(txtBox);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to control where you dynamically add elements from your code-behind, add a `PlaceHolder` control to the page and append them there.  Something like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ucReportTextBox.ascx.cs" Inherits="Intranet.UserControl.ucReport" %>
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuery" runat="server" Width="250px" />
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phAdditionalTextBoxes" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

(Note: It's not entirely clear where you want your dynamic text boxes added, so move the `PlaceHolder` accordingly.)

And in the code:

```
TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
txtBox.ID = "txtBox";
txtBox.Width = 170;
phAdditionalTextBoxes.Controls.Add(txtBox);
```

Answer (score 0):

The textboxes are being added to the end of the page because that's where `Page.Form.Controls.Add(txtBox);` puts them, yiou are adding textboxes to the end of the Page holding your UC,

Add a `Placeholder` control to your UC, then add the new textboxes to the placeholder.